# Distinguishing large integers from near integers in python

Tags: python-3.x, integer, long-integer, floating-accuracy, math.sqrt

I want to avoid my code mistaking a near integer for an integer.  For example, 58106601358565889 has as its square root 241,053,109.00000001659385359763188, but when I used the following boolean test, 58106601358565889 fooled me into thinking it was a perfect square:

```
a = 58106601358565889
b = math.sqrt(a)
print(b == int(b))
```

The precision isn't necessarily the problem, because if I re-check, I get the proper (False) conclusion:

```
print(a == b**2)
```

What would be a better way to test for a true versus a near integer?  The math.sqrt is buried in another definition in my code, and I would like to avoid having to insert a check of a squared square root, if possible.  I apologize if this is not a good question; I'm new to python.

Comment: Should it return `true` is that what you want?

Comment: It should return False, If my understanding is correct

Comment: The first print(b == int(b)) I want to be false.

Comment: Jeptha, Check my answer with Decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import math
from decimal import *

a = 58106601358565889
b = np.sqrt(a)
c = math.sqrt(a)
d = Decimal(58106601358565889).sqrt()


print(d)
print(int(d))

print(c)
print(int(c))

print(b)
print(int(b))
```

o/p

```
241053109.0000000165938535976
241053109
241053109.0
241053109
241053109.0
241053109
```

I would say use `decimal`.

**Expected code :**

```
from decimal import *
d = Decimal(58106601358565889).sqrt()
print(d == int(d))
```

o/p

```
False
```

Comment: `Decimal` still does calculations to limited (though configurable) precision. Doing all your math in `Decimal` just postpones the problem to even larger input sizes unless you perform additional configuration and secondary checks.

Comment: Thank you, Decimal did the trick.  I hadn't known about that option.

Comment: Thanks user2357112, I will have to look into the limits of precision for `Decimal`.

Comment: @Jeptha: As an example of this solution not working, try it with `a = 10000000000000200000000000002`. That's not a square, but you'll get `True` anyway.

Comment: You're right, [user2357112](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), I still need to double check that one with:  `int(math.sqrt(a)**2) == a`, which correctly gives `False` for the `a` you mention.

Comment: `Decimal` did work for the particular variable value I initially ran into, and I'll have to keep an eye out for the limits of `Decimal` precision now, too.

Comment: @Jeptha: But the double-check still isn't good enough. Try it with `a = (10**28+1)**2`, which *is* a square, and the double-check will say it's not.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a matter of distinguishing integers from non-integers, because `b` really is an integer*. The precision of a Python float isn't enough to represent the square root of `a` to enough digits to get any of its fractional component. The second check you did:

```
print(a == b**2)
```

only prints `False` because while `b` is an integer, `b**2` still isn't `a`.

If you want to test whether very large integers are exact squares, consider implementing a square root algorithm yourself.

<sup>*as in 0 fractional part, not as in `isinstance(b, int)`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out; that was a bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the precision of the `int` that is the problem - it's the limited precision of floats

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(58106601358565889)
241053109.0
>>> math.sqrt(58106601358565889) - 241053109
0.0
```

I think the double check would be the obvious solution

Comment: So maybe the double-check is truly necessary?

Comment: @Jeptha: The double-check isn't even good enough; it has its own problems. For example, it fails on `a = 100000000000000000001**2`.

Comment: @Jeptha, any floats larger than that will always be integral. Perhaps you can just test `(a == b*b)`

Comment: What about decimal  ?

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library. It has a function for calculating the integer square root and also the integer square root plus remainder. There are no precision constraints.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.isqrt(58106601358565889)
mpz(241053109)
>>> gmpy2.isqrt_rem(58106601358565889)
(mpz(241053109), mpz(8))
>>>
```

Disclaimer: I maintain `gmpy2`.